# Adding Azure AD Authentication to the project failed: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

While configuring azure AD from visual studio, I'm getting this error:

> Adding Azure AD Authentication to the project failed:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

I found that it's due to writeback option not enabled on Azure AD, but I verified against Azure AD - it's properly set. This issue is coming only when I'm using app id uri to configure but when I'm using client id it's working fine.

[image: image of error message]

Comment: Can you add more detail on what exactly you clicked, what values you provided, etc?

Comment: i clicked on configure azure ad in visual studio. it asked to enter domain name, app id uri ,client secret. i entered that values and after that i'm getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the issue was the server settings on the project. The project was linked to a local site on IIS. Removing the link and changing the setting to IIS Express fixed the issue

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should use client id , client id represents your application and is unique identifier for the application.App ID URI are used when requesting permissions to a resource application, or acquiring an access token for a resource application.

Please refer to AAD Graph Application object schema for more details on these https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#application-entity . Check the appId and identifierUris properties.

Comment: okay. here is the thing. if you are using only web application you can use client id to configure azure ad. but if you are using webapi you have to use app id uri. so in my case we have angular js spa with web api in same project. so while configuring visual studio is asking app id uri. also we confirmed with microsoft support and they confirmed same.

Comment: From visual studio you can create a new app so you don't necessary need a client id

Comment: @alallo, when create a new web app, vs help you create a new azure ad app in AAD, and configure the client Id in the web.config , client Id is needed when making web app login with azure ad accounts.

Comment: @NanYu-MSFT in my case a was not creating a new web app and I was adding azure AD to an existing project. Sorry should have mentioned that